# Computing $\lim_{x\to-\frac\pi2}\frac{e^{\tan x}}{\cos^2x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

how can i compute: $\lim_{x\to-\frac\pi2}\frac{e^{\tan x}}{\cos^2x}$?

i tried l'hopital's rule  but it's like a loop.

also if it can be done without that rule i'd like to know how.

Thanks.

Comment: Using Taylor series is *always* an alternative.

Comment: yes, but it's kind of the hard way i guess. intuitively i can see the limit is zero tho.

Comment: Think about the limit from the right and from the left of $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. Can they be the same?

Comment: Let $y=-\frac\pi2-x$ and it would be simple!

Comment: @user296113 - do you mean to use $\cos(a+b)$?

Comment: @user296113 Does the Taylor series of $e^{tan x}$ centered at $-\pi/2$ exist?  I am thinking I get $f^{(n)}(-\pi/2) = 0$ for all of the derivatives.... $e^{tan x}$ is discontinuous at $-\pi/2.$

Comment: This limit is infinity as x  approaches from the left, and 0 as x approaches from the right.

Comment: @DougM The limit doesn't approach anything. it exists or it doesn't, but it's not moving around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.

Let $x \to -\dfrac \pi2^-$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\tan x &=\frac{-\cos (x+\frac{\pi}{2})}{\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{2})} =\frac{-1}{x+\frac{\pi }{2}}+O\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)
\\\\\cos^2 x&=\sin^2 (x+\frac{\pi}{2})\sim\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to -\dfrac \pi2^-$,
$$
\frac{e^{\tan x}}{\cos^2x} \sim \frac{e^{\large -\frac{1}{x+\frac{\pi }{2}}}}{\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} \to \infty\, \left(=\text{"}\frac{e^{+\infty}}{0^+}\text{"} \right).
$$

Let $x \to -\dfrac \pi2^+$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\tan x &=\frac{-\cos (x+\frac{\pi}{2})}{\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{2})} =\frac{-1}{x+\frac{\pi }{2}}+O\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)
\\\\\cos^2 x&=\sin^2 (x+\frac{\pi}{2})\sim\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to -\dfrac \pi2^+$,
$$
\frac{e^{\tan x}}{\cos^2x} \sim \frac{e^{\large -\frac{1}{x+\frac{\pi }{2}}}}{\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} \to 0\, \left(=\text{"}\frac{e^{-\infty}}{0^+}\text{"} \right).
$$

Comment: thank you! your last step seems a bit intuitive it's still $0/0$ how come it's zero?

Comment: @matt "Exponential zero" versus "polynomial zero". You are welcome.

Comment: got it , thanks again for the detailed answer.

Comment: Setting $X=\frac1{x+\frac\pi2}$, one has $\lim_{X \to \infty}X^2e^{-X}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exist.  The denominator goes to zero and the numerator goes to either one or infinity because $lim_{x->-\pi/2}tan(x)$ doesn't exists.  It goes to infinity from the left and negative infinity from the right.  Therefore the top goes to either 0 or infinity and the limit goes to infinity.

Comment: yes that i get but how do you show that it goes to zero?

Comment: "the numerator goes to either one or infinity"  No, the numerator goes to 0 fast from the right

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to-\frac\pi2}\frac{e^{\tan x}}{\cos^2x}$$

when x is close to $-\frac {\pi}{2}$, $$\sin(x) \lt -0.5$$

so $$\frac{e^{\tan x}}{\cos^2x}\lt \frac{e^{\frac {-0.5}{\cos x}}}{\cos^2x}$$ and we can use squeeze rule.

let $t = \cos x$, we can transform the limit to,

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac {-0.5}t}}{t^2}$$

let $y=e^{\frac {-0.5}t}$, $t=- \frac {0.5}{\ln y}$

$$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y}{(\frac {0.5}{\ln y})^2}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y{(\ln y})^2}{0.25}=0$$

End

Comment: for squeeze rule , don't you need also a lower bound?

Comment: That is 0 (or g(x)=0 if you like).

Answer (score 0):

If you recognize some special limits in this expression, the rest is relatively easy.

- $\lim_{x\to \infty} xe^{-x}=0 $
- $\lim_{x\to 0} xe^{-x}=0$

Begin with the substitution: $$\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=\sec^2(x)=\tan^2(x)+1$$ Rewriting the limit expression: $$\lim_{x\to -\frac{\pi}{2}}(\tan^2(x)+1)\space e^{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to -\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan^2(x)\space e^{\tan(x)}\space + \space \lim_{x\to -\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\tan(x)} $$ If we make the substitution $-\tan(x)=y$, we get: $$\lim_{y\to \infty} y^2 e^{-y}\space +\space \lim_{y\to \infty} e^{-y}=0+0=0 $$